# Scala - Method Parameters - def function: Row => Message = { row => {

Tags: scala, function

Coming from Java background trying to understand this Scala code:

```
def function: Row => Message = {
  row => {
    // code
    // code
  }
}
```

As I understand we pass a function that returns type Message? And then we actually implement row? Why first Row is capital and second is not?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a *method* that returns a *function* which receives a `Row` and returns a `Message`. You'd call it like this: `val msg: Message = function(row)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's break it down.

`def function`

Declare a method named function that has no inputs.

`:Row => Message`

The return type is a function that take a `Row` as input and returns a `Message`

`= row => {...}`

Define and anonymous function with a single input named row.  This is the function that is returned (in Scala the last thing in a block is returned so you don't need to use the `return` keyword).  Scala is able to figure out what the input and output types of this function should be because they have to match the return type you declared for the method.

Comment: The first `Row` is a type, the second is just a variable name and could be anything. variable names start with lowercase by convention.

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand we pass a function that returns type Message?

No. Nothing is being passed. The method `function` doesn't have any parameters, it doesn't take any arguments, so you can't pass any.

> And then we actually implement row?

No. Nothing is being implemented. There are no abstract members or abstract interfaces here to implement.

> Why first Row is capital and second is not?

It doesn't have to be. It's just a convention. Types are usually written in PascalCase, parameters, fields, and methods in camelCase. (Actually, it's the exact same thing in Java.)

A rough Java equivalent would look something like this:

```
java.util.Function<Row, Message> function() {
  return row -> {
    // code
    // code
  };
}
```

As you can see, there really isn't much difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

The return type is a function that takes type `Row` and returns `Message`. There should be some higher level implementation of that function.

Check this link, it will help you understand:
https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/scala-cookbook/9781449340292/ch09s08.html

Answer (score 0):

Not quite.

`def` means that you are defining a method. In this case it takes no argument and its return type is `Row => Message`.

So the `function` method you are defining returns a function that takes a `Row` and returns a `Message`.